# How to add if condition in an map Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in ReactJs. I have code below:

```
{users.map((user, index) => ( 
    <tr key={user.id}> 
        <td>{ index+1 }</td> 
        <td>{user.name}</td> 
        <td>{user.email}</td> 
        <td>{user.gender}</td> 
        <td>{user.status}</td> 
    </tr> 
))}
```

My question is how to add if condition in the code, e.g:

```
if (user.status) == "0"
    return "In-Active"
else if (user.status) == "1"
    return "Active"
else if (user.status) == "2"
    return "Disabled"
```

Comment: You may wrap your status texts in an object like `let statusTexts = { "0": "In-Active", "1": "Active", "2": "Disabled" }`, then can render as `<td>{statusTexts[user.status]}</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in a function:

```js
function getStatusLabel(status) {
  if (user.status) == "0"
    return "In-Active"
  else if (user.status) == "1"
    return "Active"
  else if (user.status) == "2"
    return "Disabled"
}
```

```js
users.map((user, index) => ( 
    <tr key={user.id}> 
        <td>{ index+1 }</td> 
        <td>{user.name}</td> 
        <td>{user.email}</td> 
        <td>{user.gender}</td> 
        <td>{getStatusLabel(user.status)}</td> 
    </tr> 
))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create an object for `status`:

```
const status = {
   '0':'In-Active',
   '1':'Active',
   '2':'Disabled'
 }

{users.map((user, index) => ( 
    <tr key={user.id}> 
        <td>{ index+1 }</td> 
        <td>{user.name}</td> 
        <td>{user.email}</td> 
        <td>{user.gender}</td> 
        <td>{status[user.status]}</td> 
    </tr> 
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @John you can achieve this by adding third row-

```
{users.map((user, index) => ( 
    <tr key={user.id}> 
        <td>{ index+1 }</td> 
        <td>{user.name}</td> 
        <td>{user.email}</td> 
        <td>{user.gender}</td> 
        <td>{user.status}</td>
        <td>{user.status == "0"? "In-Active": user.status =="1"? "Active":"Disabled"}</td>
    </tr> 
))}
```

Hope this solution will solve your query, if you still facing issue, just lemme know, i will help you.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method and check user status on there

```
function renderuserStatus(user) {
if (user.status) == "0"
  return "In-Active"
  else if (user.status) == "1"
   return "Active"
  else if (user.status) == "2"
   return "Disabled"
}

{users.map((user, index) => ( 
<tr key={user.id}> 
    <td>{ index+1 }</td> 
    <td>{user.name}</td> 
    <td>{user.email}</td> 
    <td>{user.gender}</td> 
    <td>{renderuserStatus(user)}</td> 
</tr> 
))}
```